# Which is better to design dynamic worlflow diagrams : Graphiti or Draw2D?

Tags: raphael

Which is more better , powerful and flexible between Graphiti or Draw2D,
As i need to design dynamic workflow diagrams.
So please let me know which is better ?
As I am also unable to make Diamond shape so please tell me how to make diamond shape using graphiti ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you need "diamonds" or boxes with round corners - Graphiti is the choice.
Draw2D is more to create Workflow diagrams with HTML-Dom elements or complete Forms 
as workflow nodes.

If you are unable to create your own figures, neither Draw2D nor graphiti is the right
tool for you. Both are JS libs and not a complete application.

Greetings

Comment: HiAndreas,
Thanks for reply, most of the requirements are fulfilled by Graphiti for workflow but few problems what i am having rite now are :
 - Can not resize the elements, like i have made diamond now by editing your ResistorBridge Example, but your Resistor bridge is not resizable.So can you please provide me solution for that?

 - How to add arrow to the end of connector?

Your both libraries are very helpful and cross browser compatibility ( for SVG and VML ).

Thanks for the wonderful library, I m just starting it so i having bit problem. Hope you help me for the same by suggesting soln.

Comment: The "ResistorBridge" is an example for a SVG-Import. Please inspect Rectangle or Circle .....for resizeable elements. Arrows are not possible with graphiti at the moment. I start to implement this in the next days.